# Can individual feature properties be retrieved from the CartoDB.js API?

Tags: javascript, carto, jquery

I'm building [an application](http://wboykinm.github.io/geosprocket-labs/google/wards/) that uses CartoDB to show users how a proposed redistricting plan would affect them. The user enters an address and that fires a ST_Intersects query to CartoDB, the result of which is always two polygons: one is the old ward, one is the proposed ward. Type "40 Bradley Street, Burlington, VT" into the search box to see how this works.

[image: appscreen]

I'd like to push answers to the indicated questions (e.g. "Where will my polling place be?") as well. However, this requires the ability to retrieve individual attribute values from the query results, and I can't figure out how to do this. [Here is the structure](https://github.com/wboykinm/geosprocket-labs/blob/master/google/wards/index.html#L175-L186) I'm trying to use after running cartodb.createLayer();

```
var 1990ward = cartodbproperty.ward[1];
    var 2010ward = cartodbproperty.ward[0];

    if (1990ward == 2010ward) {
        $('#wardchange').text("No. You will remain in ward " + 2010ward + " under the proposed plan.");
    }
    else {
        $('#wardchange').text("Yes. You are currently in ward " + 1990ward + ", but you would be in ward " + 2010ward + " under the proposed plan.");
    }

    $('#distchange').text("The " + cartodbproperty.district + " District");
    $('#pollchange').text(cartodbproperty.pollingplace);
```

The "cartodbproperty" variables are dummies because I can't figure out how I would use the cartodb.js API to select the "ward" attribute value of the query-result feature where "year" = 2010.

I believe I could pull this off with a parallel call to the SQL API - which could then be parsed as JSON - but that seems horribly inefficient. How can I get this data from the CartoDB.js API?

Thanks as always for the great toolset!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you are missing a few important bits. Right now you are doing,

```
cartodb.createLayer(map, {
  user_name: 'geosprocket',
  type: 'cartodb',
  sublayers: [{
    sql: "somesql",
    cartocss: "somestyle"
  }]
})
```

but you also need to tell it you want interaction,

```
cartodb.createLayer(map, {
  user_name: 'geosprocket',
  type: 'cartodb',
  sublayers: [{
    sql: "somesql",
    cartocss: "somestyle", 
    interactivity: 'cartodb_id, column_2, column_3'
  }]
})
```

Then, in your function, you can get at that data with the feature events. You can wire them up after adding your layers to the map, e.g.

```
.done(function(layer){
  var sublayer = layer.getSubLayer(0);
  sublayer.bind('featureOver', function(e, latlon, pxPos, data, layer) {
     console.log(data.cartodb_id);
  });
});
```

Comment: I [added that in](https://github.com/wboykinm/geosprocket-labs/blob/master/google/wards/index.html#L175-L180), but nothing logs or updates the DOM where indicated. I'm also not strictly aiming for featureOver interactivity. I want to pass these attributes to their respective DOM elements when [the search function fires](https://github.com/wboykinm/geosprocket-labs/blob/master/google/wards/index.html#L131). Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Include cartodb_id here, https://github.com/wboykinm/geosprocket-labs/blob/master/google/wards/index.html#L171 to start

Comment: I must still be doing something wrong [here](https://github.com/wboykinm/geosprocket-labs/blob/master/google/wards/index.html#L176-L181); the id isn't logging at the console and the data.district value isn't being pushed to the DOM.

Comment: don't forget to enable interaction: sublayer.setInteraction(true)

Comment: Awesome. That got the data through! Thanks! But is there a way to bind it to the query function instead of [featureOver](https://github.com/wboykinm/geosprocket-labs/blob/master/google/wards/index.html#L178)? I need these DOM elements updated when the search result comes back, not when the user mouses over the result.

Comment: But for the sake of performance, that data isn't retrieved by the client until the hover! You could load it all as json with the SQL API and skip all the hover stuff directly, https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb.js/blob/develop/doc/API.md#cartodbsql

Comment: I went with the [parallel SQL API call](https://github.com/wboykinm/geosprocket-labs/blob/master/google/wards/index.html#L179-L193), and it's still super-speedy. Thanks so much for the assistance!